# Facing errors in logstash

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

When i defined the pattern for parsing apache tomcat and application log files in logstash we are getting the following error .
Sample log file is :

```
2014-08-20 12:35:26,037 INFO [routerMessageListener-74] PoolableRuleEngineFactory Executing the rule -->ECE Tagging Rule
```

config file is :

```
filter{
   grok{
    type => "log4j"
    #pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} \[\w+\[%              {GREEDYDATA:thread},.*\]\] %{JAVACLASS:class} - %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}"

    #add_tag => [ "level_%{level}" ]
 }



   date {
        match => [ "logdate", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
   }
}
```

Unknown setting 'timestamp' for date {:level=>:error}

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not show a setting 'timestamp' for your date filter. I suspect you had started with the example here which used timestamp setting that used to be in older versions of date filter. You correctly fixed it for newer version of logstash to use match setting but perhaps had not saved your change. I have no problems using above filter with logstash-1.5.3.

Here is my complete config file. Note I am still testing it but it seems to be working to import a JBoss log with Log4J log messages imported from an existing log file.

```
input {
  tcp {
    type => "log4j"
    port => 4560
  }
  stdin {
    type => "log4j"
  }
}

filter {
  grok{
    type => "log4j"
    #pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} \[\w+\[%{GREEDYDATA:thread},.*\]\] %{JAVACLASS:class} - %GREEDYDATA:message}"
    pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}"

    #add_tag => [ "level_%{level}" ]
 }

  date {
    type => "log4j"
    match => [ "logdate", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    exclude_tags => "_grokparsefailure"
  }

  # Catches normal space indented type things, probably could be removed b/c the other multiline should do everythign we need
  multiline {
    type => "log4j"
    tags => ["_grokparsefailure"] # exclude anything we already handled
    pattern => ".*"
    what => "previous"
    add_tag => "notgrok"
  }
}


output {
  gelf {
     host => "localhost"
     custom_fields => ["environment", "PROD", "service", "BestServiceInTheWorld"]
     }
  # Print each event to stdout.
  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```